# Can't get zinnia to work in my django application

Tags: python, django, zinnia

Upon accessing the `test server/weblog/` url on `localhost`, in an environment with "latest everything stable" (python 2.7, django 1.4.1, apache 2.2.22) I'm getting:

```
NoReverseMatch at /weblog/

Reverse for 'zinnia_entry_add' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1/weblog/
Django Version:     1.4.1
Exception Type:     NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    

Reverse for 'zinnia_entry_add' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.

Exception Location:     /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py in render, line 424
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version:     2.7.3
```

Excerpt from `settings.py`:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.admindocs',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.comments',
    'image_labeler',
    'tagging',
    'mptt',
    'zinnia',
)

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
    'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
    'django.core.context_processors.media',
    'django.core.context_processors.static',
    'zinnia.context_processors.version',
    )
```

and from `urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Example:
    # (r'^lastpixel/', include('lastpixel.foo.urls')),

    # Uncomment the admin/doc line below and add 'django.contrib.admindocs' 
    # to INSTALLED_APPS to enable admin documentation:
    # (r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    (r'^weblog/', include('zinnia.urls')),
    (r'^comments/', include('django.contrib.comments.urls')),
    (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    (r'^$', views.Index),
    (r'^login/?$', views.Login),
    (r'^logout/?$', views.Logout),
    (r'^register/?$', views.Register),
    (r'^i$', include('image_labeler.urls')),
    (r'^i/', include('image_labeler.urls')),
    (r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': '/home/lastpixel/web/media', 'show_indexes': True}),
    (r'^.*$', views.Index),
)
```

The application works otherwise (withouth the zinnia blog). Any idea what I might be doing wrong? Much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem after updating zinnia.
This helped me out, although I didn't expect a solution in mysql:

First, edit `/etc/my.conf`

```
[client]
default-character-set=utf8

[mysqld]
default-character-set = utf8
skip-character-set-client-handshake
character-set-server = utf8
collation-server = utf8_general_ci
init-connect = SET NAMES utf8
```

Second, restart mysql

Taken from:
[zinnia on github](https://github.com/Fantomas42/django-blog-zinnia/issues/144)

Comment: Wow. Unfortunately I have postgres and `psql mydb -c 'SHOW SERVER_ENCODING'
 server_encoding 
-----------------
 UTF8
(1 row)`. But I'll keep an eye on this!

Comment: I am using sqllite ? How can modify it for sqllite ?

Answer (score 2):

It is likely that it is a namespace problem. In your error page, do you see the inline error highlight something that looks like `{% block 'zinnia:zinnia_entry_add' %}`? This is part of the `zinnia` name space, indicated by the `zinnia:` part of that definition. If you see something like this, you likely just need to add the correct namespace to your URLs:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    #.....
    (r'^weblog/', include('zinnia.urls', namespace="zinnia")),
    #.....
)
```